# Redirect the URL to another, in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a webpage which was built with core php, now its been updated to codeigniter mvc. Problem which i am facing is, users are trying to enter the old URL path

> example:  www.website_name/old_path

now since the mvc layout, it wont work and will get 404 error. i want to redirect the clients who enters  www.website_name/old_path  for the new one

> www.website_name/index.php/new_controller/new_view.

Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank You!

Comment: Have you any idea about routes in codeigniter?

Comment: Not much, please explain how to implement this in that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all remove `index.php` config file.
Open `config.php` and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Then create HTACCESS file in application/ folder

having this code....

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Now index.php is removed from your URl....

STEP 2) open application/config/routes.php file
Now here define your desired web URL

```
$route['mycontroller/(:any)'] = "mycontroller/user_detail/$1";
```

So,Your URL Will be ..
www.website_name/new_controller(or xyz)/

Here you can also change the controller name differently using routes So no one can get the exact name of controller/method name....To Do such customization refer this URL
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Current and Old Codeigniter Doc's located here now http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: Its working when i put the .htaccess in the root/, it didnt work when placed in application/ folder

Comment: @vikram don't make folder inside application i just meant to say Go in application/  and create htaccess file

Answer (score 2):

You can use 301 redirect for this type of issue.

Put this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^www.website_name/old_path www.website_name/index.php/new_controller/new_view [L,R=301]
```

or use 301 redirect of codigniter  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

```
// with 301 redirect
redirect('/article/13', 'location', 301);
```

Comment: Current and Old Codeigniter Doc's located here now http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 2):

As Sumit mentioned, you should use URL Routing for this.

In the routes file you can create a list of all the redirects that you want like so:

```
$route['old_path'] = "new_controller/new_view";
```